# Eclipse indigo not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, java-7

i am working with eclipse indigo , but it gives me strange behavior .
    when i start eclipse indigo by double clicking on eclipse.exe it is not working ,it is showing (Not Responding) message continuously.
    but if i start it from the command prompt than it is working fine .
    i don't know what is the reason behind that.
    i am attaching screen shot

1) eclipse which is not responding

2) command prompt from where it is working fine

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4hHY.png)

[Eclipse Not Responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2LVx.png)
    following is the my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms80m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Try with reducing MaxPermSize to 256M which comes as default. Also put Xms256m.

Comment: sorry @vijendra its still not working properly .

Comment: from your command prompt error it seems there may be some jdk compatibility issue. try changing jdk version or uninstall Groovy plugin if possible.

Comment: yes but i have other eclipse version too , like juno , kepler none working properly , work properly only if they are started from command prompt .

Comment: Are you installing Groovy support into all of those versions?

Comment: No i have installed groovy only in the eclipse indigo.

Comment: If all the versions of eclipse are only working from command prompt then may be there is something which is available when opening eclipse from command prompt like JAVA_HOME. Check if you have set JAVA_HOME properly.

Comment: i have set following environment variables 
1 ) JAVA_HOME ==> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
2) JRE_HOME ==> C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

Comment: you should update to eclipse neon and java 8